# WCF Service References : Managing App.Config

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

My solution is composed of several Class Library projects. One of these include a Service Reference. The functionality exposed by this particular assembly will need be called from several other assemblies.

How can I manage the configuration file(s) for this solution, so that I don't have to repeat the `<system.serviceModel>` contents on every single assembly making use of the web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach (repeating in every app's config) is the default and recommended way to go - you cannot easily have config files for class-library assemblies (you can, but it's a fair bit of work to get them to actually work - not worth the trouble).

If you can't live with this, you could definitely create your WCF client proxy in code, bindings, options, endpoints and all. You do gain a bit of ease-of-use (no more config needing to be put into every app calling the class library), but you loose a bit of flexibitlity (endpoint addresses and binding options are now hard-coded).